# LDAP python 3 (not working) but in PHP (working) where is the problem?

Tags: python, php, python-3.x, ldap

Python 3 code - not working:

```py
import ldap3 as ldap

SERVER_NAME = 'serverip'
DN = 'dc=mydomain,dc=com,dc=br,ou=people'
USERNAME = 'no-reply'
PASSWORD = 'mypassword'

server = ldap.Server(SERVER_NAME,port=389, get_info='ALL')
connection = ldap.Connection(server, user='{}\\{}'.format(DN, USERNAME), password=PASSWORD)
connection.open()
if connection.bind():
    print('Authenticated!')
else:
    print('Not Authenticated')
    print(connection.result)
```

**This is print result**

> Not Authenticated
> {'result': 34, 'description': 'invalidDNSyntax', 'dn': '', 'message': >'invalid DN', 'referrals': None, 'saslCreds': None, 'type': 'bindResponse'}

PHP code - working:

```php
<?php
$username="no-reply";
$pass="mypassword";

$ldapconfig['host'] = 'serverip';
$ldapconfig['port'] = '389';
$ldapconfig['basedn'] = 'dc=mydomain,dc=com,dc=br';
$ldapconfig['usersdn'] = 'ou=people';
$ds=ldap_connect($ldapconfig['host'], $ldapconfig['port']);

ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
$dn="uid=".$username.",".$ldapconfig['usersdn'].",".$ldapconfig['basedn'];

if ($bind=ldap_bind($ds, $dn, $pass)) {
  $ldap_result = @ldap_search($ds, $dn, "uid=".$username);
  $result = ldap_get_entries($ds, $ldap_result);
  print_r($result);
} else {
  print_r(new Exception("Error"));
}
?>
```

I'm writing Python 3 code to use LDAP, but authentication is not working. However, my old code written in PHP works successfully. Where is the problem in my Python code?

Comment: Thank you [khelwood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3890632/khelwood) to your English revision and to reformat my code

Answer (score 0):

The key words in the error message is `'invalid DN'`. It's complaining about the format of the username in the call to `ldap.Connection`. You're doing:

```
user='{}\\{}'.format(DN, USERNAME)
```

Which would result in this string:

```
"dc=mydomain,dc=com,dc=br,ou=people\no-reply"
```

But that's not a valid format. Because you're using the distinguished name (DN) of the domain, it's assuming the whole string is a DN, but then the `\no-reply` at the end throws it off.

Your PHP code is doing this:

```php
$dn = "uid=" . $username . "," . $ldapconfig['usersdn'] . "," . $ldapconfig['basedn'];
```

Which will result in this string:

```
"uid=no-reply,ou=people,dc=mydomain,dc=com,dc=br"
```

So modify your Python code to use the same value for the username.

You may even get away with passing just the username (`"no-reply"`), depending on what your LDAP server is. It may or may not work:

```
connection = ldap.Connection(server, user=USERNAME, password=PASSWORD)
```

Answer (score 0):

## **I managed to solve the problem, it was necessary to rewrite the code simplifying the commands.**

```
from ldap3 import Server, Connection, ALL, SUBTREE

username = 'no-reply'
password = 'mypassword'
serverName   = 'ip_address'
DC = 'ou=people,dc=domain,dc=com,dc=contry'
server = Server(serverName, get_info=ALL)
conn = Connection(server, 'uid='+username+','+DC, password, auto_bind=True)
conn.search(search_base = DC,
                             search_filter = '(uid='+username+')',
                             search_scope = SUBTREE,
                             attributes = ['cn', 'givenName', 'company', 'title' ],
                             paged_size = 5)
print(conn.entries)
```